# Tabindex for radios

Tags: html, css, tabindex

```
        <label>What is your gender?</label><br>
        <input id="male" name="items" type="radio" value="male" checked>
        <label for="male">Male</label><br>
        <input id="female" name="items" type="radio" value="female">
        <label for="female">Female</label><br>
        <input id="not-to-say" name="items" type="radio" value="not-to-say">
        <label for="not-to-say">I prefer not to say</label><br>
```

I have radio buttons and I want to set my tabindex to go through all of them how can I make it?

Comment: why not just add a tabindex to each input?

Comment: I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the expected action. Once the tab stop happens, you need to use the arrow keys to select the right one. Not the tabs.

[image: preview]

Also you could use `tabindex` for each input, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: I appreciate it.